# How do you define a new language specification for color syntax highlighting in Xcode 4?

Tags: macos, xcode, syntax-highlighting

For Xcode 3 there is plenty of information available about how to define a syntax highlighting specification for a language not already supported in Xcode.  But there doesn't seem to be any information on how to do it for Xcode 4.  For example, I would like syntax highlighting for Common Lisp, Forth, and other languages not appearing in the "file type" drop down in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this [just isn't possible](http://www.openradar.me/9111936) yet.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931670/447015) the API's that supported this in Xcode 3.0 were outdated even for that version, and have been completely removed in 4+.

There is a project called [solarize](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) that *may* do what you're looking for, but I didn't see any of the languages you listed and support for Xcode 4 is still limited.  I personally use Xcode only for Objective-C programming, and then use eclipse or TextWrangler for the rest

---

### [Eclipse for Mac OS X](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx)

[image]

Eclipse is great for the more intensive projects, that have multiple classes, and are actual projects.  It's mainly developed for Java, but also supports Python, C/C++, PHP, and [Lisp](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-lispcusp/) (probably even more)

[image]

---

### [TextWrangler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12)

[image]

TextWrangler is great for small edits or files.  Things that I need to pull up quick, and make smaller edits to and supports tons of languages as well.

[image]

---

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223132/how-to-set-an-external-editor-in-x-code-4-2) that Xcode can even open external editors when the files are associated to that editor.  While this isn't the perfect solution, it appears to be the only one for now.